# Databricks integration with Kafka Schema Registry

Tags: schema, databricks, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams, azure-databricks

I have developed a databricks pipeline which consumes data from Kafka topic. Currently I am processing by manually defining the schema in Pyspark.

I understood that Kafka schema registry is also setup by Kafka team and I received registry URL.

Please guide me how to connect to schema registry through pyspark program in Databricks. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Databricks provides extended versions of `from_avro` and `to_avro` functions that are accepting the Kafka Schema Registry URL as a parameter, something like this:

```scala
val df = spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafkaURL)
  .option("subscribe", "t")
  .load()
  .select(
    from_avro($"key", "t-key", schemaRegistryURL).as("key"),
    from_avro($"value", "t-value", schemaRegistryURL).as("value"))
```

There is a plenty of information on that topic - [example notebook](https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/schema-registry-integration/index.html#avro-data-and-schema-registry.html), [blog post from databricks](https://databricks.com/blog/2019/02/15/how-to-work-with-avro-kafka-and-schema-registry-in-databricks.html), [blog post from Confluent](https://www.confluent.io/blog/consume-avro-data-from-kafka-topics-and-secured-schema-registry-with-databricks-confluent-cloud-on-azure/), [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/structured-streaming/avro-dataframe.html).